# Why can't I get Axios to set CSRF token headers?

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, axios, next.js

I have an HTTP-only cookie that was set by Django for session-based authentication. When I try to make a POST request in my Next.Js app I get `detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."`. I know I need the `X-CSRFToken` header but Axios won't set it for me. The cookies are being sent in the request just not as a header. My post request looks like this:

```js
axios
      .post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/shops`, createShopFormData, {
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',
        xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
        console.log(error.response?.data.message);
      });
  };
```

[image: Cookies are shown in request.]

[image: Show after request headers]

Edited to show after User-Agent. Token changed cause I was messing with it between edits.

Comment: Can you show request headers after *User-Agent*

Comment: That's where Request Headers ends and my Payload is shown.

Comment: Maybe your `csrftoken` cookie is HttpOnly? If so, you can't read it from browser. I think it should not be HttpOnly by default, but worth to check it.